# Installing separate plugin for GIMP on Mac os lion

Tags: macos, gimp

I use GIMP for my editing and I needed to convert an RGB file into CMTK. I found that I can do that using a GIMP plug-in called Separate. I followed all instructions for MAC as specified in the documentation to get it installed, but it wasn’t successful.

The page for the plug-in I am trying to install:

http://www.blackfiveservices.co.uk/separate.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Try this build of GIMP for mac: http://www.partha.com/

I haven't tried it yet (downloading now), but documentation says it has Separate+ bundled in.